# MouseDown events stop firing in WPF window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, events, button

I have a WPF window in which I subscribe to mouse down events for when the user clicks anywhere, even outside of the window:

```
void RightClickWindow_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
        Point mousePositionInApp = Mouse.GetPosition(this);
        Point mousePositionInScreenCoordinates = PointToScreen(mousePositionInApp);
        if (mousePositionInScreenCoordinates.X < Left || mousePositionInScreenCoordinates.X > Left + Width || mousePositionInScreenCoordinates.Y < Top || mousePositionInScreenCoordinates.Y > Top + Height)
        {
            Close();
        }
    }
    catch { }
}

void RightClickWindow_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Mouse.Capture(this, CaptureMode.SubTree);
}
```

If the click is out of bounds, I dismiss the window. This works well except in one special case that I'm trying to fix but can't figure out how. Here's where it stops working:

I have a simple WPF `Button` in XAML. If I left-mouse click this button, and while the mouse is down, I drag the cursor outside of the bounds of the button, and then I release the left-mouse button, these capture events no longer fire. Why is that, and how can I fix my code for this special case?

Comment: Do you mean they no longer fire in the instance where you release the button, or that they no longer fire *ever*?

Comment: They no longer fire *ever*.

Comment: the problem is your Window loses its Mouse Capture. To reproduce your problem, we have other ways such as try focusing any elements inside your window, then try clicking outside your window, it won't be closed as expected because it's been lost the mouse capture. I think you should not try doing something like this, its behavior is very unreliable. When your Window has mouse capture all the time, you cannot handle the Title bar normally (cannot interact with it). First you have to focus some element in your window before being able to drag the Title bar. Then the window loses mouse capture...

Comment: @KingKing No, this whole thing is not for dragging a title bar around. The right click window has no title bar, its coded in pure WPF to not display standard UI elements like that; instead it is a right-click menu that has custom styling applied to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click the `Button` the `Window` loses mouse capture which is why the `MouseDown` event is never called again.  Closing on the `Deactivate` event should work for your scenario.

Comment: So much simpler to just override the Deactivated event like this and Close. Thanks so much! Of course, I had to add some concurrency checks to make sure the window was not closing yet by overriding the OnClosing event, but, it was nothing. :)